# Not getting correct values of potentiometer in the channel1 and channel2 in stm32f103

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, adc, stm32cubeide

I have been trying to read values from two potentiometers connected to channel1 and channel2 in ADC1 and read the values through UART in a serial Terminal,but unable to do it. It either comes random value or a same value for both the POTS. ADC works perfectly for a single channel.
The board I am using is STM32F103(Bluepill).
I have my own UART library that I am using to read.

**ADC initialisation**
in the regular channel configurations, I made two different functions of both thechannels

```
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  //ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */

  /** Common config
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 2;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
```

For configuring the regular channels I made two different functions as these will be called in other functions with a multiplication factor.

```
void ADC_SET_CH1()
{
     //MX_ADC1_Init();
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
     sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_28CYCLES_5;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
      HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_IRQn);
}

 void ADC_SET_CH2()
 {
     //MX_ADC1_Init();
     ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
     sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
       sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_2;
       sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_41CYCLES_5;
       if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
       {
         Error_Handler();
       }
       HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_IRQn);
 }
```

The different functions that I made in order to call them in the while loop to read the values in serial terminal:

```
float read_value1()
 {
     ADC_SET_CH1();
    //rawData=0.1525*readAdc(0x01);
    // HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);
     rawdata1=0.1525*HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
    return rawdata1;
 }
 float read_value2()
  {
     ADC_SET_CH2();
    //rawData1=0.1525*readAdc(0x02);
    //HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);
     rawData=0.1525*HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);

    return rawData;
  }
```

**MAIN:**

```
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "uart.h"
#include "stm32f1xx_it.h"

char *readbuffer;
float rawData=0.0f;
float potValue=0.0f;
char *readbuffer1;
float rawdata1=0.0f;
float potvalue1=0.0f;
int main(void)
{
  
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);
```

**while 1:**

```
while (1)
  {
     potValue=read_value1();
  readbuffer=(convertIntToString(potValue));
  writeString1("pot0:");
  writeString1(readbuffer);
  //writeString1("\n");
  HAL_Delay(500);
  writeString1("     ");
  potvalue1= read_value2();
  readbuffer1=convertIntToString(potvalue1);
  writeString1("pot1:");
  writeString1(readbuffer1);
  writeString1("\n");
}
}
```

**The IRQ function:**

```
  void ADC1_2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_2_IRQn 0 */
    adcValue=ADC1->DR;
    //HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);
  /* USER CODE END ADC1_2_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_ADC_IRQHandler(&hadc1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_2_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_2_IRQn 1 */
}
```

Comment: I have not looked at this in detail, so don't knoe if this is tghe only issue and therefore constitutes an answer, but it is certainly not necessary to call `ADC_SET_CH1()` and `ADC_SET_CH2()` on every read - those are one-time-set-up/initialisation actions.

Comment: This is too broad. You should narrow the problem, debug first if you get meaningful reads without using the uart.

Comment: @Clifford isn't it necessary to initialize the channels? or should I do it in the main function.  ADC_SET_CH1() is to configure the channel 1.

Comment: @perencia I was checking through uart since I am not having a debugger right now. I want to know if my approach is correct.

Comment: Clearly not.  The ADCs on STM32 are complex beasts.  I'll have to think about it, but generally you can set the channel ranks and start the conversion self-clocked running continuously then just asynchronously read the DR registers for each channel. If you ise the injected channels and one regular channel you can do that for up to 5 channels without the need for interrupts.  Using interrupts for ADC except for very slow sample rates of long conversion times is usually ill-advised.  You would do better ot either "busy-wait" or use DMA transfers.

Comment: ...  For potentiometer readings rather then signal-processing, then the busy-wait makes sense.  The conversion time may not be much longer then the interrupt context switch and processing.  TBH the code looks a bit "cargo-cult".